# Digital Miner - Ore Specification with OreDict

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mekanism

At great expense and effort, I've successfully built the Digital Miner from Mekanism. It's an excellent mining tool, but I'm having trouble with the config, specifically telling the miner which ores I want mined. I thought the best way to do this would be to put it in inverse mode and then "whitelist" the ores that I didn't want. For example, I'm not doing thaumcraft, so I don't want the miner to mine entropy infused stone. Equally I don't want cinnibar ore. However, I can't find the right "code-names" to type in the OreDict filter. By code-names I mean the block names as they appear in the code (e.g. oreRedstone for redstone ore). So far I have stone, cobblestone and sandstone, but typing in "sand" gives me a blank ore filter. Also, entropy infused stone is too many characters to fit in the filter. How can I tell the miner what I want mined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mekanism has a "Dictionary" item that shows the ore dictionary name for any item you right-click. I would definitely recommend building it.

Wildcards also work in the filters, so I usually forgo specific filtering and just mine `ore*` and get literally every ore registered in the ore dictionary.

For names that are too long, you can type it most of the way and put a * at the very end.

Comment: cheers :) I knew about the ore* thing, but I didn't want ores from like thaumcraft or ars magica